# Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality using generalised Young inequality in Lorenz spaces

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, interpolation-theory, young-inequality

I want to prove that

$$\left| \left| \frac{1}{|x|^a} \ast f \right| \right|_q \lesssim ||f||_p$$

with $1 < p < q < \infty$ and $a= n \left(1 + \frac{1}{q}- \frac{1}{p} \right)$ using a version of the Young inequality in Lorenz spaces, that is:

$$||f \ast g||_{p_1 , q_1} \lesssim ||f||_{p_2 , q_2} ||g ||_{p_3 , q_3}$$

where $|| \cdot||_{p,q}$ is the norm of the Lorenz space $L^{p,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and I have the relations:

$$ \frac{1}{p_1}+ 1= \frac{1}{p_2} + \frac{1}{p_3} \quad \frac{1}{q_1}=\frac{1}{q_2}+ \frac{1}{q_3}$$

So the problem is: if I choose $p_2= n/a$ and $q_2 = \infty$ so that I have $||\frac{1}{|x|^a}||_{\frac{n}{a} , \infty}$ bounded, I either have to consider $|| |x|^{-a} \ast f ||_{q,p}$ and $||f||_p $, or $|| |x|^{-a} \ast f ||_q$ and $||f||_{p,q}$. I can't take $|| |x|^{-a} \ast f ||_q$ and $||f||_p$ together.

Is there some obvious norm-inequality in Lorenz spaces that I am missing?

P.S. The inequality is due to O'Neil (he invented it in the sixties I think), I don't know the reference though

Edit: Lorenz spaces are defined with the following norm:

$$||f||_{p,q}= p^{\frac{1}{q}} \left|\left| \lambda \mu\{|f(x)|>\lambda\}^{\frac{1}{p}}\right|\right|_{L^q (\mathbb{R}_+, \frac{d\lambda}{\lambda}}$$

with $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $1 \leq q \leq \infty$. If $q=\infty$ they are the weak $L^p$ spaces. There is anothere characterization of the Lorenz norm though, which is more useful in order to prove some inequalities. It is based on the so called "decreasing rearrangement function". See here if interrested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space#Definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refined Young inequality that you need is the following; 
$$\lVert f\ast g\rVert_r\le C \lVert f\rVert_p\lVert g\rVert_{q, \infty}, $$ where the numerology is the same as in the standard Young, that is $$1+\frac1r = \frac1p+\frac1q.$$ I took this from Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin, "Fourier analysis and nonlinear PDEs" https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642168291, Theorem 1.5.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I already solved my problem, because I found an inequality between Lorenz norms which I didn’t know (it makes use of an equivalent norm I was not familiar with, the so called “rearrangement norm”, or something like that, I don’t remember)

Comment: @tommy1996q: it would be great if you could post some details. I vaguely remember attending a course on this kind of spaces, but of course I forgot almost everything. :-)

Comment: Done! If you want to see more, I bet there is something on "Interpolation spaces" by Bergh,Lofstrom

Comment: Oh great. But why is this useful here? (if you have time, of course)

Comment: Well, I don't remember where I read it, but apparently using that other characterization with the rearrangement norm, you are able to prove that if $r>p$ then $||f||_{q,r} \lesssim ||f||_{q,p}$, that is exactly what I needed here, because in the left hand side I had $||\cdot||_{q,p}$ where I wanted $||\cdot||_q$, and this inequality gives me that.